# How to solve Mean-reverting diffusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I'd like to learn how to solve the following mean-reverting process equation:
\begin{equation}
dS_{t}=a(b-S_{t})dt + S_{t}\sigma dw
\end{equation}

I have solved the equation without the presence of $S_{t}$ before $\sigma$. My solution is like the following:
\begin{equation}
dS_{t}=a(b-S_{t})dt + \sigma dw
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
d(e^{at}(b-S_{t}))=ae^{at}(b-S_{t})dt -ae^{at} dS_{t}
\end{equation}
and replace  $dS_{t}$ and solve the problem. However, when $S_{t}$ exists as the multiplier before $\sigma$ in the problem, I could not come up with a practical function to solve it analytically. What is the effective way to solve the problem? In other words, what would be the practical function, instead of $e^{at}(b-S_{t})$, for differentiation?

Comment: I don't know of any nice closed form solution $S_t$ when the diffusion coefficient is $\sigma S_t$. My guess would be there is no "nice" solution for this.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241024/determining-properties-of-stochastic-differential-equation-as-drift-tends-to-0/4241118#4241118) reproduces an explicit solution from Wikipedia for the case $b=0.$ There might be more.

Comment: I though the only way is to solve it using the Kolmogorov forward pde. No other solution has crossed my mind yet!

Comment: @FarhadTahmasebi , in fact, for $b\not=0$ there is also a [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4299855/itos-lemma-and-ansatz/4300161#4300161).